# How to update mysql database changes on database server automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, svn, cron

Client want that database structure update should be automatic and error free.

**For Example:**

- DeveloperA added new `SQL query 1` to central place.
- DeveloperB added new `SQL query 2` to central place.
- Cronjob runs at night and `SQL query 1` and `SQL query 2` is updated on database server.
- Developer added new `SQL query 3` to central place.
- Cronjob runs at next night and `SQL query 3` is updated on database server.

Is it possible or at what level we can automate this update process?

**What is the best standard uproach to update database changes daily when there are many developers working on a project and adding SQL scripts to database?**

**We are using:**

```
Linux dedicated server.
Crontab
PHP
MySQL
SVN
Shell Scripting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up three directories;

- pending
- success
- failure

New scripts are dropped into "pending". A process runs from cron and picks these up, and tries to process them. Successfully processed files are moved to "success", otherwise they are moved to "failure".

A log file records all activity by the scheduled process, and emails or alerts are generated upon failure.